# Finishing multiple animations in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four '.dist' elements. They have a different preloaded data (exactly: 57 , 27 , 17 , 244). I want to animate incrementing, and I wrote this code:

```
$('.dist').each(function() {
    var count = parseInt($(this).text())
    var incr = 0
    var that = $(this)
    var animation_time = 500
    var interv = animation_time / count

    $(this).text('0')

    var fd = setInterval(function() {
        if (incr < count){
            incr++
            that.text(parseInt(incr))
        }
    } , interv)
    console.log(interv)
})
```

The problem: The biggest value finishes 100 light years after the rest.

Console.log (directly from this code) returns:

8.928571428571429 
18.51851851851852 
29.41176470588235 
2.0491803278688523

Thats the values which I/We expected, but I think every interval has a specific delay, but I dont't know how to detect and correct that delay.

I want to finish all of incrementations from 0 to 'var count' in time ~= 500ms. I want to start all of incrementations in the same time, and finish every one in the same time.

Sorry for my primitive querstion but I started my adventure with js/jq only 6 months ago, and I can't find the answer by google. Maybe I'm retarted or something. Thanks for help.

edit: html

```
<div class="info back2 border corners1">
        <span class="dist">56</span>  seriali<br>
        <span class="dist">27</span>  obejrzanych<br>
        <span class="dist">17</span>  oczekuje<br>
        <span class="dist">244</span>  sezonów<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your html and/or create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: HTML, not PHP. And put it in your question, not a comment. You're setting different intervals for each of them, which I'm guessing is not what you want? `var interv = animation_time / count`

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I pasted it. I want to finnish all of incrementations from 0 to 'var count' in time ~= 500ms. I want to start all of incrementations in the same time, and finish every one in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems: One is that you end up with a very small interval, and second that the calculated interval becomes a float. `SetInterval` can only handle whole milliseconds, not fractions, so your calculation will always be off. Better to set a start and end time and calculate the difference.

This is the most accurate way to do time calculations in Javascript anyways.

```
$('.dist').each(function() {
    var count = parseInt($(this).text());
    var incr = 0;
    var that = $(this);
    var animation_time = 500;

    $(this).text('0');
    var time_start = new Date();

    var fd = setInterval(function() {
        var time_passed = new Date() - time_start;
        if (time_passed >= animation_time) {
            clearInterval(fd);
            time_passed = animation_time;
        }
        that.text(Math.round(count*time_passed/animation_time));
    } , 10);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xau91msr/

Or if you don't care about the actual time for the animation and want browser stutters etc to not count as passed time you can increment `time_passed` yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/jevjyf3m/

Comment: Also [window.requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) if your browser supports it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed number of steps and increment proportionally, then your counts will reach their ends together, also don't forget to clear the interval once the animation is complete.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtvtdasz/10

```
clearInterval(fd);
```

Comment: Your effect is better than main, but still, not perfect. I know, I could leave that problem with that solution, but I know - that should have a better solution. I'm learning from zero, and I don't want to miss the basics.

Comment: there a certain limits to setinterval, what you can do is descrease the animation steps to reduce the overhead effect of setinterval, see my answer update

Comment: It look's good, thanks a lot. I not have been idle, and I tried some variations based on pristine code. What You think about this? https://jsfiddle.net/pdd3g7q3/2/

Comment: your new version is running alot slower and the increments are visible, you are better off with my last version https://jsfiddle.net/rtvtdasz/5/

Comment: I tested your code ( https://jsfiddle.net/rtvtdasz/5/ ) with some higher values of ( var animation_time ), and different values in span's and it still looks smoothly. I was looking for that effect. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The problem isn't any overhead with `setInterval`, the problem is that when you round off the interval you get an incorrect time that becomes apparent the more times you iterate. The same issues from the question are in all of your provided solutions.

Comment: The solution is still wrong. I added a "DONE" text at the end of the animation so you can really tell that they don't finish at the same time. https://jsfiddle.net/rtvtdasz/6/

Comment: Yes, proportional increments is a better solution, I didn't get time to look at it again.

Comment: Yeah now the result is correct but it's also exactly like my posted solution. https://jsfiddle.net/jevjyf3m "having a fixed number of steps and incrementing proportionally" isn't at all what it does though. Feel free to post your own code that actually does that.

Comment: As requested, Updated :)